# PHP is inserting special cheracters e.g Â in the database table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

**Description :**
I have

```
var returned_name = '<a href="#" contenteditable = "false" class = "tag">'+$("#n_" + cd).html()+'</a> &nbsp'+",";
```

being appended to a content editable div. Upon clicking the button I extract all the text form the div like the following

```
nerd_interests = $("#nerd_interests").text();
```

and send it to the php successfully. I get pure text that is between the tags e.g form

```
<div> Fruit </div>
```

i get Fruit perfectly.. Now when I save it to my database table I see following

Â Fruit Â

**PHP :**

```
mysql_query("UPDATE  `table_name`.`coloumn_name` SET  `name` =  '$nerd_name' where id = '4'");
```

Whats happening ... I cant seem to find any reason .. Is it suppose to be like that or is there something I am doing wrong ??

Comment: please show your database query... maybe the "spaces" are changed into special chars, you should have a look at the charset you use...

Comment: obviously you are not able to parse the div tags correctly and its making them unicode A hat. So its something to do with what you do with the string before you insert. I would venture a guess you are doing something with. sql_escape_string that is doing that for you.

Comment: @Julo0sS I have updated my post with the query u asked I am getting data by simple post method no extra function is being used to filter the data

Comment: need to know what is INTO "$nerd_name" ... !! maybe try to execute this query before inserting something : "SET NAMES 'UTF8'"

Comment: @Julo0sS you were right spaces were the problem but not on client side but in php returned html.. Thanks !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this being returned from the php

```
<div id = "n_g_'.$i.'" contenteditable = "false"> &nbsp '.$tags[$i].' &nbsp </div>
```

So I removed `&nbsp` and then returned the html. It worked!! the spaces I was creating with help of `&nbsp` To make the returned text fit perfectly into the tag was creating this problem.

Now i am getting a space free text on which php and mysql are working perfectly.